# Custom message error for: Message was rejected due to XML Validation errors; nested exception is

Tags: spring-integration

I'm reading an XML file validated against a xsd file. If there is a validation error a workflow is listing on the channel IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME. I'm getting the error message. The business is not happy with the default message (see below). Now I'm parrsing the result to display only the relevent information. is there any way to access only to the substring that give the xml tag that is not correct or missing?

Message was rejected due to XML Validation errors; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.xml.AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException: Multiple causes:
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '1900' is not a valid value for 'date'.
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '1900' of element 'BirthDate' is not valid.

```
@Bean
public MessageFilter validatexml() throws IOException, AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException {
    XmlValidatingMessageSelector validate_xsd = new XmlValidatingMessageSelector(myfile.xsd,
            XmlValidatingMessageSelector.SchemaType.XML_SCHEMA);
    validate_xsd.setThrowExceptionOnRejection(true);
    return new MessageFilter(validate_xsd);

}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFileFlowLocal() throws IOException, AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
            .handle(validatexml())
            .transform(new UnmarshallingTransformer(jaxbMarshaller()))
            .handle("payloadTransformer", "myObject")
            .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
            .handle(httpGateway())
            .handle("responseProcess","process")
            .get();
}

    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
            .handle(handleMessage())
            .get();
}

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your requirements, but you definitely can take a look into an `AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException` and uses its `List<Throwable> getExceptions()` to get access to all the errors individually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm handling the error inside a workflow "return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)" at that point I do have only a Message<?> bean comming from the error chanel. The system catch the error and send it to the error channel I can't get the  List<Throwable> so I need to refactor the code?

Comment: No, you are good. That message sent to the error channel is exactly an `ErrorMessage` and its `payload` is a `MessageRejectedException` with that mentioned `AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException` as a cause. So, try in the debug get access to the message content in your `handleMessage()` and you'll see what I am talking about.

Comment: Hi Artem, Now I can access the most relevent part of the error message. Thank you for your support